# Applying symbology changes to all feature classes using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro

I'm using this code to remove all decimal places within the symbology results of Graduated Colors. I can get it to apply to one feature class, but I can't figure out how to get it to apply to all of them (I have a total of 15).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps()[0]
lyr = m.listLayers("BCBS*")[0]
sym = lyr.symbology
if sym.renderer == "GraduatedColorsRenderer":
    breaks = sym.renderer.classBreaks
    for b in breaks:
        b_int = b.label[0:-7]
        b.label = b_int
lyr.symbology= sym
```

All the feature classes begin with "BCBS" so I thought that `BCBS*` would apply the desired results to all the feature classes but it didn't. Then I realized that `[0]` was only applying it to the first feature class, but I still can't figure out how to apply it to all feature classes that begin with "BCBS"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called a "Loop" in python - you want to loop through all the layers.  Currently you are specifying only one layer.  Instead of `lyr = m.listLayers("BCBS*")[0]` get a list of all your layers, such as `layers = m.listLayers("BCBS*")`, and then loop through that list of layers using `for lyr in layers:`

Note that those two lines are the only things I have changed in your code (as well as indenting the lines in the `for`), so it assumes that you want the symbology set the same way for every layer in the list.

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps()[0]
layers = m.listLayers("BCBS*")
for lyr in layers:
    sym = lyr.symbology
    if sym.renderer == "GraduatedColorsRenderer":
        breaks = sym.renderer.classBreaks
        for b in breaks:
            b_int = b.label[0:-7]
            b.label = b_int
    lyr.symbology = sym
```